# Does the MongoDB "extent was empty" indicate a missing index?

Tags: mongodb

I have seen a lot of questions about the MongoDB log entry such as

```
Tue Mar 11 09:42:46.995 [conn1044] info DFM::findAll(): extent 0:2f000 was empty, skipping ahead. ns:mydb.mycoll
```

I know this is because there is allocated empty space in the MongoDB datafiles caused by deleting previous data. Commenters usually say you can ignore this message or compact the DB if you want to recover the diskspace.

But why is MongoDB looking in an empty spot anyway? Does this message also indicate that I am missing an index and that the DB is scanning the datafiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you are receiving can happen after a large amount of data is deleted. An extent is just a data file, or "bucket" where data can be stored. If you delete a lot of data an extent can end up empty. This is not a problem as the extent will get filled up again as data is inserted.

> Does this message also indicate that I am missing an index and that the DB is scanning the datafiles?

No, this is just an informational message logged periodically when MongoDB finds an empty extent.
As you mentioned, the message can be ignored or you can address it by running a repair to free up allocated space.
If your collection has frequent deletions or document growth, you should also consider enabling the [usePowerOf2Sizes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/) collection allocation option. This allocation strategy will allow MongoDB to more effectively reuse deleted space by allocation records by rounding up to the nearest power of 2 (rather than using a dynamic [Padding Factor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/#padding-factor). FYI, PowerOf2Sizes is now the default allocation strategy for new collections in MongoDB 2.6.
Note that usePowerOf2Sizes only affects new record allocations once the flag is enabled. I would recommend you run a repairDatabase after enabling this flag so any historical allocations are also updated.

Comment: Thanks, we do have at lot of deletion so this is good advice.

Comment: Please note that usePowerOf2Sizes is default as of MongoDB 3.0, and the flag therefore is deprecated.